# NodeJS: Unable to save data to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, mysql2

I am sending the following JSON array to a code

```
[
    {
        "idseller_portfolio_item": 1,
        "image_url": "https:://something.com/image3.png"
    },
    {
        "idseller_portfolio_item": 1,
        "image_url": "https:://something.com/image4.png"
    }
]
```

I need to read the JSON Array and insert the data into the database. Below is my code, I am trying to do a batch insert.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.saveSellerPortfolioItemImages = (event, context, callback) => {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    if (event.body == null && event.body == undefined) {
        var response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
        callback(null, response)
    }
    else {
        let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
        console.log("body", body);
        

            let result = [];

            for(let i in body)
                result.push([i, body [i]]);

            console.log("MyResult: "+ result);

            //allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
            const sql = "INSERT INTO seller_portfolio_item_images (idseller_portfolio_item, image_url) VALUES ?";
            con.execute(sql, [result], function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.toString());

                    if (err.toString().indexOf('cannot be null') >= 0) {
                        var response = errorCodes.not_null_parameters;
                        callback(null, response);
                    }
                    var response = errorCodes.internal_server_error;
                    callback(null, response);

                }
                else {
                    var response = {
                        "statusCode": 200,
                        "headers": {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        "body": JSON.stringify({ insertId: result.insertId }),
                        "isBase64Encoded": false
                    };
                    callback(null, response)
                }
            });
        


    }
};
```

This is my table

[image]

However this gives me the following error. The `primary key` is auto generated so I dont have to insert it from my code.

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: `let body = JSON.parse(event.body)`, What is the body? can you show us the `console.debug(body)`?

Comment: `(idseller_portfolio_item, image_url) VALUES ?` has two columns but only one value. This should probably be `(idseller_portfolio_item, image_url) VALUES (?, ?)`

Answer (score 1):

The '?' in query is telling that one parameter will be coming from an array
so if you want to add two parameters you would use (?,?) and so on

```
            //allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
            const sql = "INSERT INTO seller_portfolio_item_images (idseller_portfolio_item, image_url) VALUES ?";
            con.execute(sql, [result], function (err, result) {
```

so, in your case you need to change it as follows-

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.saveSellerPortfolioItemImages = (event, context, callback) => {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    if (event.body == null && event.body == undefined) {
        var response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
        callback(null, response)
    }
    else {
        let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
        console.log("body", body);
        
//-------------------updated-------------------------------
         //   let result = [];

            for(let i in body){
               // result.push([i, body [i]]);

            console.log("MyResult: "+ result);

            //allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
            const sql = "INSERT INTO seller_portfolio_item_images (idseller_portfolio_item, image_url) VALUES (?,?)";
            con.execute(sql, [body[i].idseller_portfolio_item,body[i].image_url], function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.toString());

                    if (err.toString().indexOf('cannot be null') >= 0) {
                        var response = errorCodes.not_null_parameters;
                        callback(null, response);
                    }
                    var response = errorCodes.internal_server_error;
                    callback(null, response);

                }
                else {
                    var response = {
                        "statusCode": 200,
                        "headers": {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        "body": JSON.stringify({ insertId: result.insertId }),
                        "isBase64Encoded": false
                    };
                    callback(null, response)
                }
            });
        
}
//-------------------end-------------------------------

    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code works. But i noticed it only works when there are only 2 elements in the array. If there are more than 2, the rest of the el;ements will not be inserted. why is this?